# Swift 'self' used before 'super.init' call when try to use a delegate

Tags: swift

When I try to use CBPeripheralManagerDelegate in the init method I am getting 'self' used before 'super.init' error. Any idea whats wrong here?

```
     import CoreBluetooth
        
        @objc
        public class L2CapChannelManager : NSObject, CBPeripheralManagerDelegate {
               
            private var peripheralManager: CBPeripheralManager?
            private var deviceConnectedMethodChannel: FlutterMethodChannel
            
            @objc
            public init(deviceConnectedMethodChannel: FlutterMethodChannel) {
                self.peripheralManager = CBPeripheralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
                self.deviceConnectedMethodChannel = deviceConnectedMethodChannel
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing `self` to the initialiser of `CBPeripheralManager` before your object has been fully initialised. If you change your code to this it will compile:

```
import CoreBluetooth
        
@objc
public class L2CapChannelManager : NSObject, CBPeripheralManagerDelegate {
               
    private var peripheralManager: CBPeripheralManager?
    private var deviceConnectedMethodChannel: FlutterMethodChannel
            
    @objc
    public init(deviceConnectedMethodChannel: FlutterMethodChannel) {
        self.deviceConnectedMethodChannel = deviceConnectedMethodChannel
        super.init()
        self.peripheralManager = CBPeripheralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
    }
}
```

Another solution would be to delay the creation of the `CBPeripheralManager` by using a lazy property:

```
import CoreBluetooth
        
@objc
public class L2CapChannelManager : NSObject, CBPeripheralManagerDelegate {
               
    private lazy var peripheralManager: CBPeripheralManager? = {
        CBPeripheralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
    }()
    private var deviceConnectedMethodChannel: FlutterMethodChannel
            
    @objc
    public init(deviceConnectedMethodChannel: FlutterMethodChannel) {
        self.deviceConnectedMethodChannel = deviceConnectedMethodChannel
    }
}
```

Comment: I think using computed property could resolve the issue. Without initialising in the init().  private var peripheralManager: CBPeripheralManager {
        CBPeripheralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
    }

Comment: Using a computed property would create a new CBPeripheralManager every time it was accessed. A lazy property would probably work.